# Disable copying entire line when nothing is selected in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste, intellij-14

I have recently started using Intellij and I noticed that by default, when you do ctrl+c for copying something when you have nothing selected, it copies the entire line into the clipboard overriding what I had in there before.

This is really annoying yet I cannot seem to figure out how to disable it. I am aware that there is a paste history you can use however this is not what I am after, I just want to disable it like you can do with sublime text.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour so that when I press ctrl+c and nothing is selected it just leaves the clipboard alone?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Since version 2021.2 there is a dedicated `Don't copy/cut the current line when invoking the Copy or Cut action with no selection` setting for this in `Preferences | Advanced Settings` on the Mac, `Settings | Advanced Settings` on other platforms.

For older IntelliJ Platform based IDE's the setting is more hidden:

Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (<kbd>Ctrl (Cmd on Mac)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), type *Registry* and select the `Registry...` item that appears. Enable the `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection` option there. Be careful with the other configuration options, because it is possible to break your IntelliJ IDEA installation with an incorrect setting.

[image: Registry window]

Comment: Awesome. I dont know why this is hidden so deep within Intellij but that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @Bas this has not worked for years the above shortcut must have been changed either way you must provide an alternative way to open it in case it does not work. this is by far the most-viewed intellij issue as no sane dev on earth wants to copy emptiness and yet the solution is held out of reach.

Comment: @Dilapidus I made him update the answer. the above now works yes.

Comment: Heck! That drove me crazy!

Comment: This solution doesn't work in RubyMine (and I suspect Jetbrains moved it, since this answer is getting old). You can now find this as a settings option in Preferences > Advanced Settings > Don't copy/cut the current line when invoking the Copy or Cut action with no selection.

Comment: There is no "Preferences"

Comment: It's named "Settings" on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 6):

In Mac OS X:

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.
2. Type `registry` and press <kbd>return</kbd> to
   open the Registry.
3. Enable the `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection` option.
4. Click Close.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it should be same as in WebStorm, or someone might be searching WebStorm solution as I did:

- Open the settings: File > Settings > Advanced Settings (bottom of the list).
- Start typing "editor".
- Check the `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection`
- Click "OK" or "Apply"

On: WebStorm 2022.3.1
[image: On: WebStorm 2022.3.1]